Why is an attempted upgrade of RAM with the same specs seemingly can't be used?
I use HP Pavilion Gaming 15-ec0xxx with 8GB RAM default. It still has one slot for upgrade so I decide to buy one.The current RAM is Samsung SODIMM DDR4 8GB 2666Mhz, so I buy exactly that.
Here's the comparison of old and new RAM after install:
lshw info:

Here's the old vs new RAM stick:

I use Linux, and I can see my RAM with lshw, I can even see 16 GB in BIOS. But I can't see it with htop. I even simulate 15GB process and it failed while only able to use 10GB (Note: I have 2 GB VRAM so in total I have 8+2 GB to begin with). Seems like the OS can't use the new RAM.
At first I thought this was OS fault, but when I tried to boot with only the new RAM, it can't boot and capslock flash 5 times slow and 3 fast and that is a systemboard problem. I thought the RAM's broken so I returned it to the store and they give me a new RAM stick. I tried the new stick and still the same.
This is my lshw -C memory output before I add new RAM:
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: AMI
       physical id: 0
       version: F.13
       date: 03/03/2022
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: d
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 0
          serial: Unknown
          slot: Bottom - Slot 1 (left)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2667 MHz (0,4 ns)
          product: M471A1K43CB1-CTD
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 1
          serial: 14222581
          slot: Bottom - Slot 2 (right)
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2667MHz (0.4ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: f
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 10
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 2MiB
       capacity: 2MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 11
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3

The new RAM has exactly same specs  but still can't run. The only different is the old RAM is SA1-11 and the new RAM has code SA10 -10.
Have anyone ever had the same problem?

Note: "Have anyone ever had the same problem?" is not a good question to ask here. This may be an invitation to discussion, but the site is not a discussion forum, we answer questions. The answer to the quoted question is either "yes" or "no". Will such answer help you? Probably not. So consider [edit]ing and asking e.g. "what may be the cause?" or "how can I make the new RAM work?". Also please don't post images of text; post text instead.

memtest is a good idea here I think

Not the same specs - the top DIMM is single rank  (1R), the bottom one dual rank. Accordingly, the latter has twice the chip count.

Those two sticks are not identical. One is single rank the other is dual rank, it shouldn’t matter, but it appears it does matter
